# Guide for Carrot2 in PDF

Tags: carrot2

Could you please say if there is a pdf (or doc) version of the documentation? If yes, where can I find it?

If such does not exist, I guess it would be great to create such.
PDF allows reading the file in Mendeley Desktop program, underlining parts that are important for me and putting comments. THis would be a great advantage to compare with the html version of the guide.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome, just go to [the Carrot2 online help manual](http://download.carrot2.org/head/manual/) and choose "Print...". In the "Destination" box on the left-hand side change it to "Save as PDF" and click OK. This functionality is built-in to Chrome by default.

For other browsers I'm sure there are add-ins/plugins you can find or you can always use a third-party PDF driver like [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/).